# Is there any way to get all token transfers of a specific block number?

Tags: web3js, transactions, json-rpc, etherscan

I am looking for a way to get all erc20 token transfers with specifying block number only.

For ETH there is already a way exists [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber).

I have done some search and found this method to find transfers of a specific address.

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&sort=desc&address=SOME_ADDRESS&startblock=BLOCK_NUMBER
```

Is there any way to list all token transfers of a specific block by just providing a block number as a parameter in any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Web3 APIs to pretty easily do this.

You just need to know that the ERC20 standard has a fixed ABI, and thus will have a fixed "method id"

```
Function: transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) 
MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
```

Any ERC20 transfer that happens in a block should start with `0xa9059cbb` since this determines which function is called in a contract.

With this information, you just need to:

- Get a block
- Get all transaction hashes
- Get all transactions
- Check the first 10 characters match

Like so:

```
window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>"));

async function getERC20Transfers(blockNumber) {
  let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
  for (var transactionIndex in block.transactions) {
    let transactionHash = block.transactions[transactionIndex];
    let transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
    if (transaction.input.substr(0,10) == "0xa9059cbb") {
        console.log(transaction)
    }
  }
}

getERC20Transfers(7210415);
```

You can find a working example which prints to your browser console here: https://jsfiddle.net/4sujyx5g/2/

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to get the exact `to_address` of the token transfer? Currently it shows contract address as `to_address`. But actual address is another address. For ex., [see here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x66ee86c467651c67485a46f438c37da8a7bfb1730225a955ff6ef3da7f06782a)

Comment: You need to look at the content of the transaction, and decode the value for the "to" address. Should be pretty easy